# TextViews disappear after many hours after closing app

Tags: android

I am creating a to-do app. I can see that my textviews are saving when you close the app and reopen it after few hours, but they disappear when you reopen the app after many hours after closing the app. Any ideas on what the problem is?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_main);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int counter = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("key2", 0);
        Log.i("counter on create", Integer.toString(counter));
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            layout.addView(createToDo(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(Integer.toString(i), "")), i);
        }
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSettings2 = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferencesSettings2.edit();
    editor2.putInt("key2", 0);
    editor2.commit();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    SharedPreferences prefs2 = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int counter = prefs2.getInt("key2", 0);
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        layout.addView(createToDo(prefs.getString(Integer.toString(i), "")));
            textList.add(prefs.getString(Integer.toString(i), ""));
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    int counter = 0;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    for (String t: textList) {
        editor1.putString(Integer.toString(counter), t).commit();
        counter++;
    }
    editor1.commit();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSettings2 = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferencesSettings2.edit();
    editor2.putInt("key2", counter);
    editor2.commit();
}

private TextView createToDo(String subject) {
    final TextView todo = new TextView(this);
    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , 180);
    todo.setLayoutParams(params);
    todo.setId(counter1);
    counter1++;
    params.setMargins(0, 1, 0, 1);
    todo.setText(subject);
    todo.setTextSize(18);
    todo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    todo.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue2));
    todo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    todo.setPadding(25, 0, 0, 0);
    todo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    todo.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this, todo, layout) {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            todo.animate().translationX(500).alpha(0f).setDuration(250).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    layout.removeView(todo);
                }
            })
                    .start();
        }
    });
    return todo;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, that would include the code where you are loading the data from some persistent store (e.g., database) into the `TextView` widgets, along with the code where you are putting that data into a persistent store.

Comment: Why do you set the `counter` to `0` in the `SharedPreferences` on `onPause`?